# Error in converting Object to String Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to convert an Object to String in JavaScript to do some String Manipulation. This is my code:

```
   var userName=String(userInfo.email);//regular email like user@email.com
   var atIndex=userName.indexof("@");
```

I got the following error:

```
TypeError: Object feraeww23d4@wo3ewwito.co2mb has no method 'indexof'
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`indexOf`

Capital `O` is important.

Answer (score 3):

The 'O' should be a capital. Are you sure you got that right?